# How to make tabs routing with React Router v6 with cross linking on nested page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make a nested routing with tabs on a page and cross-linking but no success. Please help to make it work.

1. I have a route `/files` which contains two tabs: `Raw Medias tab` and `Datasets tab`. On tab switching page url is not changed it's always the same `/files`.
   How can I make page url changes on tab switching? For example, default tab on page `/files` is Raw Medias. So how to make it: if user lands on `/files` page then page url is `/files/raw-medias`. If user switches on `Dataset tab` then page url should be `/files/datasets`.
2. Each tab has a list with clickable items. On item click item's page opens `/files/raw-medias/id`. This page has Back button. On click Back button opens `/files` page with active default tab. How to make so that on Back button click opens `/files` page with active tab for that item? For example if active tab is `Dataset tab` and user clicks on item and then on Back button then `Dataset tab` should be active.
3. Raw Media Page has a list. This list is the content of Dataset tab (cross linking). How to make so if user clicks on item in that list then he should land Dataset item page? For example, user is on `/files/raw-media/id` and click on an item in list then `/files/dataset/id` page should open. At the moment I get an error because on this this url opens `/files/raw-media/id/dataset/id`

**Codesandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-tabs-ciivld?file=/src/App.tsx

My routes:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/files",
        element: <FilesPage />
      },
      {
        path: "files/raw-media/:rawMediaId",
        element: <RawMediaPage />
      },
      {
        path: "files/dataset/:datasetId",
        element: <DatasetPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

**Tabs page**

```
    type Tab = "raw-medias" | "datasets";
    
    const FilesPage = () => {
      const [tab, setTab] = useState<Tab>("raw-medias");
    
      const handleChangeTab = (tab: Tab) => {
        setTab(tab);
      };
    
      return (
        <Stack>
            FilesPage
            <Button onClick={() => handleChangeTab("raw-medias")}>
              Raw Medias Tab
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => handleChangeTab("datasets")}>
              Datasets Tab
            </Button>
    
            {tab === "raw-medias" ? <RawMediaList data={RAW_DATA} /> : null}
            {tab === "datasets" ? <DatasetList data={DATASET_DATA} /> : null}
        </Stack>
      );
    };
```

**RawMediaPage.tsx (single item page with Back button)**

```
const RawMediaPage = () => {
  const { rawMediaId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Typography>
        This is RAW Media Page
      </Typography>
      <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
        Go Back to tab list
      </Button>

      <Stack>
        This is Dataset List on RAW Media Page
        <DatasetList data={DATASET_DATA} />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

**DatasetList.tsx (list with clickable items)**

```
 const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = (id: number) => {
    navigate(`dataset/${id}`);
  };

  return (
    <Stack>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Box onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)} key={item.id}>
            {item.name}
          </Box>
        );
      })}
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FilesPage.tsx

Configure the `FilesPage` component to couple the current matched route with a "tab". We use the `NavLink` component here to navigate between tabs ***and*** get the "tab matching" for free by using `NavLink`'s `isActive` children prop.

```
import { Stack, Typography, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const FilesPage = () => {
  return (
    <Stack gap={"30px"}>
      <Typography variant="h4" align={"center"}>
        FilesPage
      </Typography>
      <Stack direction={"row"} gap={"10px"}>
        <NavLink className="tab-link" to="raw-medias">
          {({ isActive }: { isActive: boolean }) => (
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ background: isActive ? undefined : "gray" }}
            >
              Raw Medias Tab
            </Button>
          )}
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="tab-link" to="datasets">
          {({ isActive }: { isActive: boolean }) => (
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ background: isActive ? undefined : "gray" }}
            >
              Datasets Tab
            </Button>
          )}
        </NavLink>
      </Stack>

      <Stack>
        <Outlet />
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default FilesPage;
```

css

```
.tab-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

## App.tsx

Configure the routes so the nested routes are rendered by `FilePages` as a layout route.

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import FilesPage from "./FilesPage";
import RawMediaList from "./RawMediaList";
import DatasetList from "./DatasetList";
import RawMediaPage from "./RawMediaPage";
import DatasetPage from "./DatasetPage";
import { RAW_DATA, DATASET_DATA } from "./mockData";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/files",
        element: <FilesPage />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "raw-medias",
            element: <RawMediaList data={RAW_DATA} />
          },
          {
            path: "raw-medias/:rawMediaId",
            element: <RawMediaPage />
          },
          {
            path: "datasets",
            element: <DatasetList data={DATASET_DATA} />
          },
          {
            path: "datasets/:datasetId",
            element: <DatasetPage />
          },
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Navigate to="./raw-medias" replace />
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

### RawMediaList & DatasetList

These components need to render links to the specific detail pages.

```
import { Box, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const RawMediaList = ({ data }: { data: { id: number; name: string }[] }) => {
  return (
    <Stack gap={"10px"}>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Box
            key={item.id}
            component={Link}
            to={`${item.id}`}
            sx={{
              color: "black",
              padding: "10px 20px",
              background: "lightgray",
              textDecoration: "none"
            }}
          >
            {item.name}
          </Box>
        );
      })}
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default RawMediaList;
```

```
import { Box, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const DatasetList = ({ data }: { data: { id: number; name: string }[] }) => {
  return (
    <Stack gap={"10px"}>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Box
            key={item.id}
            component={Link}
            to={`/files/datasets/${item.id}`} // <-- absolute path
            sx={{
              color: "black",
              padding: "10px 20px",
              background: "lightgreen",
              textDecoration: "none"
            }}
          >
            {item.name}
          </Box>
        );
      })}
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default DatasetList;
```

Note that `DatasetList` uses absolute paths since it is rendered by both tabs so it can't link relatively from one tab to the other.

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-make-tabs-routing-with-react-router-v6-with-cross-linking-on-nested-page]